# Subset pandas dataframe based on first non zero occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the sample dataframe:-

```
    Trade_signal

2007-07-31      0.0
2007-08-31      0.0
2007-09-28      0.0
2007-10-31      0.0
2007-11-30      0.0
2007-12-31      0.0
2008-01-31      0.0
2008-02-29      0.0
2008-03-31      0.0
2008-04-30      0.0
2008-05-30      0.0
2008-06-30      0.0
2008-07-31     -1.0
2008-08-29      0.0
2008-09-30     -1.0
2008-10-31     -1.0
2008-11-28     -1.0
2008-12-31      0.0
2009-01-30     -1.0
2009-02-27     -1.0
2009-03-31      0.0
2009-04-30      0.0
2009-05-29      1.0
2009-06-30      1.0
2009-07-31      1.0
2009-08-31      1.0
2009-09-30      1.0
2009-10-30      0.0
2009-11-30      1.0
2009-12-31      1.0
```

1 represents buy and -1 represents sell. I want to subset the dataframe so that the new dataframe starts with first 1 occurrence. Expected Output:-

```
2009-05-29      1.0
2009-06-30      1.0
2009-07-31      1.0
2009-08-31      1.0
2009-09-30      1.0
2009-10-30      0.0
2009-11-30      1.0
2009-12-31      1.0
```

Please suggest the way forward. Apologies if this is a repeated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do. Here `df[1]` refers to the column containing buy/sell data.

```
new_df = df.iloc[df[df["Trade Signal"]==1].index[0]:,:]
```

Comment: I guess one square bracket is missing. Unable to figure it out.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni, works fine for me. Did you put the column name correctly?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni feel free to let me know the error you're running into if you can't get this to work.

Comment: 'Trade Signal' is the column name. Could you please edit the code accordingly?